# Unable to run SerDe

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, ebcdic, hive-serde

We have one **ebcdic sample file**. 
It is stored in `/user/hive/warehouse/ebcdic_test_file.txt`

Cobol layout of the file is stored in `/user/hive/Warehouse/CobolSerde.cob`

We are running on Hue browser query editor. 
We also tried in CLI. 
But the same error is coming

We have added CobolSerde.jar. 
Via 
Add jar `/home/cloudera/Desktop/CobolSerde.jar`

It has been added successfully. Proof via LIST JARS.

Query

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE cobol2Hve 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.savy3.hadoop.hive.serde2.cobol.CobolSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FixedLengthInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat' 
LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/ebcdic_test_file.txt' 
TBLPROPERTIES ('cobol.layout.url'='/user/hive/warehouse/CobolSerDe.cob','fb.length'='159');
```

Error while processing statement:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. 
Cannot validate serde: com.savy3.hadoop.hive.serde2.cobol.CobolSerDe
```

1. Why is the error coming?
2. What is fb.length?

Comment: please check this issue post on github https://github.com/rbheemana/Cobol-to-Hive/issues/1

Comment: Hi tejas, did you get the answer.. i'm also getting the same error.. it would be helpflul, if you are sharing the comments